# Why is the initial state being used when I try to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component that uses hooks for state.  I have set the initial state for `home` to `{location:null, canCharge: 'yes'}`.

I then have a couple of subcomponents that call `setHome()` to update the pieces of the state they are responsible for.

One sets the `location`, and the other sets the `canCharge` property of the home state.

The setter for the `ChargeRadioGroup` works as expected, only updating the `canCharge` property and has no effect on the value of `location`.

The `PlacesAutoComplete` set however seems to have captured the initial state of home, and after setting a breakpoint inside, I see that it always is called with `home`: `{location:null, canCharge:'yes'}`.

I realize I could break this single state into two separate states, one for `location` and one for `canCharge`, but I'd like to understand why this is happening instead of implementing a workaround.

```
export default function VerticalLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [home, setHome] = useState({
    location: null,
    canCharge: "yes"
  });
  const [work, setWork] = useState({
    location: null,
    canCharge: "yes"
  });
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
        <Step>
          <StepLabel>Where do you live?</StepLabel>
          <StepContent>
            <Box className={classes.stepContent}>
              <PlacesAutocomplete
                className={classes.formElement}
                name={"Home"}
                onPlaceSelected={location => setHome({ ...home, location })}
                googleApiKey={"<API_KEY>"}
              />
              <ChargeRadioGroup
                className={classes.formElement}
                label="Can you charge your car here?"
                value={home.canCharge}
                onChange={event =>
                  setHome({ ...home, canCharge: event.target.value })
                }
              />
```

The code for the `PlacesAutoComplete` component can be seen  [here](https://bit.dev/goleary/locations/places-autocomplete/~code)

I'm guessing this has something to do with the way that this component calls it's `onPlaceSelected` prop, but I can't figure out exactly what's going on, or how to fix it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded) return;
    const config = {
      types,
      bounds,
      fields
    };

    if (componentRestrictions) {
      config.componentRestrictions = componentRestrictions;
    }

    autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      inputRef.current,
      config
    );

    event = autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", onSelected);
    return () => event && event.remove();
  }, [loaded]);

  const onSelected = () => {
    if (onPlaceSelected && autocomplete) {
      onPlaceSelected(autocomplete.getPlace());
    }
  };
```

Comment: Don't add pictures of code, add the snipets themselves.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I just updated the question with text instead of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating my original answer.

Instead of this:

```
onPlaceSelected={location => setHome({ ...home, location })}
```

This:

```
onPlaceSelected={newlocation => setHome( (prevState) => (
    { ...prevState, location:newlocation }
    ))}
```

The set state functions can take a value, and object or a function that receives the old state and returns the new state. Because setting state is sometimes asynchronous, object state with members getting set with different calls may result in captured variables overwriting new state.

More details at this link: https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Comment: This is actually a relatively new notation where the variable name is used as the property name & value as the property value (shorthad property names ES2015) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: for good measure, I implemented this suggestion to no avail. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Try this then: `onPlaceSelected={newlocation => setHome( (prevState) => ({ ...prevState, location:newlocation }))}`

Comment: Beautiful, that worked.  I'm still curious why I have to do it this way, but I forgot this syntax even existed.   If you update your answer I'll remove the downvote & accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Done. See the link in my updated answer on setState being async.